# Compare two hashes and create new hash or change existing hash with new key/values

Tags: ruby, hash

My situation:

```
hash1 = {
       "344"=> "QTC-2",
       "343"=> "QTC-1"
       }

hash2 =  {
        "QTC-1"=> 1,
        "QTC-2"=> 1,
        "QTC-3"=> 2
       }
```

I want to compare hash1 and hash2. I want to loop through the hashes and:

If hash1 value matches hash2 key (QTC-1 == QTC-1), then the new hash should become:

```
new_hash3 = {
          "344"=> '1',
          "343"=> '1'
        }
```

(Or change hash1 values instead of making a new_hash3 or change hash2 keys)

Comment: The Hash syntax is not valid. It should be like `{"344"=>"QTC-2", "343"=>"QTC-1"}`

Comment: Yeah I noticed that, but when that's how it prints in the terminal (without the hash rocket), I think b/c I pass the hash through JSON.pretty_generate

Comment: Edited post to use hash rockets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hash1 = {"344"=>"QTC-2", "343"=>"QTC-1"}
hash2 = {"QTC-1"=> 1, "QTC-2"=> 1, "QTC-3"=> 2 }


new_hash3 = hash1.each_with_object({}) {|(k,v), h| h[k] = hash2[v] if hash2.has_key?(v) }
# => {"344"=>1, "343"=>1}
```

Comment: Tried this but when I printed both hash1 and hash2 the output was the original output...

Comment: Did you try printing `new_hash3`? (I made this change just now)